# How to handle multiple mutations in parallel with react-query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-query, promise.all

I have a custom `useMutation` hook:

```
  const {
    status: updateScheduleStatus,
    reset: updateScheduleReset,
    mutateAsync: updateSchedule,
  } = useUpdateSchedule(queryClient, jobId as string);
```

Which I understand sets up the mutation but how would I use this if I wanted to do multiple parallel mutations?

I have tried to implement the following but the mutations execute prior to getting to the `Promise.all(mutations` line.

```
        let mutations: Array<any> = [];

        schedulesForDeletion.forEach(async (schedule) => {
          const resp = await monitoringService?.getSchedule(
            schedule.schedule_id,
          );
          mutations.push(
            updateSchedule({
              monitoringService: monitoringService as MonitoringServiceClient,
              schedule,
              etag: resp?.type === "data" ? resp.headers.etag : "",
            }),
          );
        });

        console.dir(mutations);

        await Promise.all(mutations);
```

I would have through that as `mutateAsync` returns a `Promise` that they would not fire in sequence but seems that they do.

Is there a way to handle this in `react-query` or am I better off just performing this with axios?  It would be useful to do in `react-query` as I need to invalidate some queries when the mutations are successful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

running multiple mutations in parallel does work with `mutateAsync`:

```
const { mutateAsync } = useMutation(num => Promise.resolve(num + 1))

const promise1 = mutateAsync(1)
const promise2 = mutateAsync(2)

await Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
```

I'm guessing in your example you push a Promise to the array, then you continue your loop and `await monitoringService?.getSchedule`. Only after that returns, you fire off the second mutation.

So in that sense, it seems that this is what's "blocking" your execution. If you push the original Promise coming from `getSchedule`, it should work:

```
schedulesForDeletion.forEach((schedule) => {
  mutations.push(
    monitoringService?.getSchedule(
      schedule.schedule_id,
      ).then(resp => updateSchedule({...})
    )
  )
})
```

Comment: How can we track the individual status of each mutation?

Comment: @king.reflex We can create an object with IDs tracking down each active mutation, add an ID key with the status before we call the mutation and then unset it inside the `onSettled` mutation callback.